# Swift class function inheritance issue

Tags: inheritance, swift

I have an issue with Swift class function inheritance, here is a example of the code:

```
class A {

    class func getName() -> String {
        return "I'm class A"
    }

    func print() -> Void {
        println(A.getName())
    }
}

class B : A {
    override class func getName() -> String {
        return "I'm class B"
    }
}

var b = B()
b.print() //This line prints out "I'm class A"
```

The last line prints out "I'm class A", my intension is to print out "I'm class B", because the instance type is class B. How should I change the code in class A function "print()" to let the class A realize the instance type is B and prints out "I'm class B"?
If I remove the "class" prefix tot he function "getName()", then it would do what I asked for, but how to do the same with the class function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `dynamicType`.

```
class A {
    func print() -> Void {
        println(self.dynamicType.getName())
    }
}
```

The example in the [Swift Language Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Types.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH31-ID445) is similar to yours, incidentally.